# Embedding a Facebook app within my Iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I need to embed a Facebook app within my Iphone app.
Setting the web page URL as the UIWebView URL does not work well.
Doing so presents only unscrollable part of the web page, as if the app URL is not fitted for 
iPhone device.
What is the proper way for doing it?

Comment: By 'embed the Facebook app' do you mean you want to add Facebook functionality to your app?

Comment: I want to get a facebook page "https://apps.facebook.com/appname/" in a tab within my app. I was told it's not a regular facebook page but it's a facebook app wuch i need to get through the facebook sdk.